# move a list of files to a list of locations

Tags: files, rename, mv

I'd like to move multiple files at the same time to specific new locations.

Say I have the following

```
wrong name  | c.txt | a.txt | b.txt |
Correct name| a.txt | b.txt | c.txt |
```

I'd then like to doe something like to do something like

```
mv ./{a.txt,b.txt,c.txt} ./{b.txt,c.txt,a.txt}
```

but I get the error

Comment: I don't understand how you are determining the names.  You first state c,a,b and a,b,c but then you move a,b,c to b,c,a.  Is there any pattern to this or are you just determining these names at random?

Comment: @jesse_b I have some files that were named wrongly (compared to their content) so a currently holds what file b should hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An addition to @Kusalananda's answer:

You can make it generic with a function:

```
mv_files() {

  local args=("$@")
  local num_args=${#args[@]}

  if [ $(bc <<< "$num_args%2") -ne 0 ]; then

    echo "Number of arguments must be a multiple of 2."
    return 1

  else

    num_files=$(bc <<< "$num_args/2")
    tmpdir=$(mktemp -d -p .)
    for (( i=0;i<num_files;i++ )); do
      local n=$(bc <<< "$i+$num_files")
      mv "${args[$i]}" "${tmpdir}/${args[$n]}"
    done

    mv ${tmpdir}/* .
    rmdir ${tmpdir}
    echo "Done."

  fi
}
```

And then you run it like this:

```
mv_files a.txt b.txt c.txt b.txt c.txt a.txt
```

or as you did it:

```
mv_files ./{a.txt,b.txt,c.txt} ./{b.txt,c.txt,a.txt}
```

or

```
old=( a.txt b.txt c.txt )
new=( b.txt c.txt a.txt )

mv_files "${old[@]}" "${new[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

```
mv ./{a.txt,b.txt,c.txt} ./{b.txt,c.txt,a.txt}
```

expands to

```
mv ./a.txt ./b.txt ./c.txt ./b.txt ./c.txt ./a.txt
```

before the `mv` utility is called.  Since there are more than two operands and since the last operand is not a directory, you get an error. If the last operand was the pathname of a directory, this would have moved all files into that directory (you would also get some errors from specifying some files twice).

Instead, move one file at a time into a temporary directory, renaming them to their correct names while doing so.  Then move them back.

```
mkdir t
mv a.txt t/b.txt
mv b.txt t/c.txt
mv c.txt t/a.txt
mv t/*.txt ./
rmdir t
```

There is no shortcut for this, the `mv` utility can only rename one file at a time.

Comment: is there another way to oneline rename the files like this then?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Other than taking the individual commands and stringing them together with `;` in-between each instead of newlines? No, not really. Not if the names can't be _computed_ somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tried by below method

aveen_linux_example ~]#  sed -n '/wrong name/p' filename | sed "s/|//g" | sed "s/ /\n/g"| sed '/^$/d'|awk '$1 !~  /wrong/ && $1 !~/name/{print $0}' > final.txt
[root@praveen_linux_example ~]# sed -n '/Correct name/p' filename| sed "s/|//g" |sed -r "s/\s+/\n/g"| sed '/^$/d'| awk '$1 !~/Correct/ && $1 !~/name/{print $0}' >final_2.txt


paste final.txt final_2.txt | awk '{print "mv" " " $1 " "  $2}'| sh
```